# Basic openUI5 Split View App

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sapui5

I'm looking to set up a two pane splitter view with openUI5 / SAPUI5

My code is as follows:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
<title>Hello World</title>

<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
src='resources/sap-ui-core.js'
data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'>
</script>

<script>
    //Set an object
    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("Splitter");
    // put the View onto the screen
    myView.placeAt('content');
</script>
</head>
<body class='sapUiBody'>
<div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Splitter.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.controller("Splitter", {

onInit: function () {

}
});
```

Splitter.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="Splitter"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.ui.commons">
<l:Splitter height="500px">
<Button height="100%" width="100%" text="Content 1">
  <layoutData><l:SplitterLayoutData size="30%" resizable="false"/></layoutData>
</Button>
<Button height="100%" width="100%" text="Content 2">
  <layoutData><l:SplitterLayoutData size="auto" /></layoutData>
</Button>
</l:Splitter>
</mvc:View>
```

However, I have nothing displaying on the page and in my Chrome Dev tools I have the following error:

'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' on index.html line 13, the set up on my view.

The library is set up correctly and is linking.

Comment: you might get more help if you set up a sample showing the error in a snippet here, or JSBin, Plunkr or similar. Debugging in our mind is hard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it fails in loading your view and thus calls `placeAt` of undefined. You should make the UI5-Framework aware of your local ressources. Otherwise it will try to fetch all ressources (like views, utilites) from the "ressources" folder which is incorrect in your case. A frequently used project structure looks like this:

```
WebContent
    | index.html
    | view
        | Splitter.controller.js
        | Splitter.view.js
```

Of course you can name the folder different. If I adapt this pattern and the code below to your project it works for me.

### index.html

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.commons"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
<!-- load "sap.m", "sap.ui.layout" and "sap.ui.commons" as you´re using them in your view -->

<script>
// make the framework aware of your ressource folder:
sap.ui.localResources("view");
// instantiate your view by its full qualified name:
var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("view.Splitter");
// put the View onto the screen
myView.placeAt('content');
</script>
```

### Controller (located in view/Splitter.controller.js)

```
sap.ui.controller("view.Splitter", {

    onInit: function() {

    }

});
```

### View (located in view/Splitter.view.xml)

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="view.Splitter"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.ui.commons">
<l:Splitter height="500px">
<Button height="100%" width="100%" text="Content 1">
  <layoutData><l:SplitterLayoutData size="30%" resizable="false"/></layoutData>
</Button>
<Button height="100%" width="100%" text="Content 2">
  <layoutData><l:SplitterLayoutData size="auto" /></layoutData>
</Button>
</l:Splitter>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `sap.ui.core.mvc.xmlview("Splitter")` instead of `sap.ui.xmlview("Splitter")`;